# How would I collect specific computer information and sort into a file?

Tags: database, vbscript, batch-file

I am an IT guy, and what I need to do is to somehow gather the following information:

- Dell Service Tag
- Computer Name
- User Name

of all users in my network, and then  sort that information into a text or Excel file.

I have tried using a VBS file, as well as creating a .bat file login script for each user, but I don't seem to be getting it to work completely.

Comment: What do you need help with? Getting the Dell service tag? Getting the information from 700 machines? Sorting the data once you've received it?

Comment: Also, is this information spread out on your system currently or do you have to wait for them to authenticate or something before you can try to get it?

Comment: I need help with creating a script, or something along those lines, to gather the bolded information, then sorting it.

Comment: I also have administrative rights to all computers, so I would not need them to authenticate.

Comment: Can you post what code you have tried?

Comment: For the creation of the list, I would use an instance of the dotnet arraylist: `Set Lst = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")`, add items by the .Add method: `Lst.Add "foo" : Lst.Add "bar"` and sort them with .Sort: `Lst.Sort`. You can use the ArrayList collecting the sorted data, or use the .ToArray method to transpose the ArrayList to a simple VBScript array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is code that gives what you ask, but in the future please post what you'v got of code, as little as it often is.

```
'Get Dell Service Tag Info
set ProSet = GetObject("winmgmts:").InstancesOf("Win32_BIOS")
Set ProSet1 = GetObject("winmgmts:").InstancesOf("Win32_SystemEnclosure")
For each Pro in ProSet
  For each Pro1 in ProSet1
    ServiceTag=Pro.SerialNumber
    wscript.echo ServiceTag
    exit for
  Next
  exit for
Next

'get username and computername, could also be asked in a batch
Set oShell     = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set oShellEnv  = oShell.Environment("Process")
sComputerName  = oShellEnv("ComputerName")
sUsername      = oShellEnv("username")
wscript.echo sComputerName & " " & sUsername
```

another more reliable way..

```
Set objWSHNetwork  = CreateObject ("WScript.Network") 
sComputerName = objWSHNetwork.ComputerName
sUsername     = objWSHNetwork.UserName
wscript.echo sComputerName & " " & sUsername
```

You could log the result to a database or to a textfile (An Excel file is not a good idea i'm afread)
Here a logging procedure to a textfile that can lateron be opened with Excel.

```
sub log (user, computer)
  dim fs,f
  set fs=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  set f=fs.OpenTextFile(Server.MapPath(".\logging.csv"),8,true)
  f.WriteLine now & "," & user & "," & computer
  f.Close:set f=Nothing
  set fs=Nothing
end sub
```

Comment: Hey Peter, for the first script, it works perfect, but is there anyway to output the information to a text document, or a excel spreadsheet?

Comment: What I plan on doing is putting this on our AD server, and running this on everyone's login script, and from there it would populate the excel spreadsheet.

Comment: @Peter, this is perfect, but this doesn't write the service tag I don't believe.

Comment: @Also, I've tried to change the location as to where the file is saving, and it doesnt seem to work.
"C:\users\xxxxx\desktop\logging.csv"

Comment: i got a script somewhere that writes the servicetag, but please ask in a new question. the location of the logfile is on the server and is best under the structure of the site itself, otherwise security issues could arise, like the parameters are set the file is UPDATED, so must allready exist, again, ask a question and you will get additional info and more elaborate script, comment here if done, but remember, publish what you allready have got, this is a site for learning and people learn a lot of codesnippets